# Parameters in an XML body data in an HTTP Request (JMETER)

Tags: xml, http, testing, jmeter

I have a problem and I can't find any solution... I am actually developing a test for a Web Service (let's call it WS).

To test it, I have an HTTP Request, with in the body data as XML. The problem is that in this XML, I would like some attributes to be variable (or parameters I could change).

For example, here is the XML file :

```
    <measure>
        <time>2020-04-07T10:45:00</time>
        <value index="0">
            <value>
                <basicData xsi:type="DATA1">
                    <data1 data1number="10">
                        <numberd1>13</numberd1>
                    </data1>
                </basicData>
            </value>
        </value>
        <value index="0">
            <measuredValue>
                <basicData xsi:type="DATA2">
                    <data2 data2number="8">
                        <numberd2>22</numberd2>
                    </data2>
                </basicData>
            </value>
        </value>
    </measure>
```

I would like to get random values or variables values for the numberd1 and numberd2. Is it possible to modify some attributes in the XML body data of an HTTP Request in JMETER?

The XML in the body data would be a template, which would change with the different parameters (number d1n number d2) that would change.

Thank you for any anwser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1/ Just replace the content between the opening and closing time tags like this :

```
  <time>${__time(yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss)}</time>
```

2/ add a Flow Control Action with a duration equals to 120000 (2min) in child of your thread group :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can, for random numeric values you can substitute hard-coded numbers with [__Random() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__Random) like:

```
<numberd1>${__Random(0,100,)}</numberd1>
```

and

```
<numberd2>${__Random(0,100,)}</numberd2>
```

this way you will have a random number from 0 to 99 inclusively each time the function is called

[image]

---

If you want the tests to be [repeatable](http://www.admarketreview.com/public_html/qa/testcases.html) another option is to pre-generate `numberd1` and `numberd2` pairs, store them into a CSV file and use [CSV Data Set Config](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733689-Using-CSV-DATA-SET-CONFIG) for feeding the request with the values from the CSV file.

Comment: Thank you a lot !

But any idea @Dmitri for the date with this specifications? :

- I will choose a start time and an end time, for example t1=2020-04-07T10:50:00 and t2=2020-04-07T11:00:00.
- I will choose the frequency, for example freq=2, which means that each 2min, 1 HTTP Request will be sent.
- All the body data will be filled with the corresponding time (Request1 with t1, Resquest2 with t1+freq, Resquest3 with t1+(2xfreq) ...)
And without forgetting that the template would be the same as before... Do you think it's possible?

Thank you again for your very precious answer!